# How to stop phone from savings all images in my emails

Tags: gallery

I have a samsung galaxy s5. for some reason it saves every email image in my photo gallery. meaning every image from the signature lines of all my emails keep saving as pictures inthe gallery and junking up all my memory...any suggestions so the gallery only saves pictures i actually take and not the same images over and over?

Comment: I imagine there must be a setting in the email app for whether or not to download images. Your other option is to find the directory where the images are stored and put a `.nomedia` file there.

Comment: If i set it to not download images, will that affect what i see when i am looking at the email itself?

Comment: Well of course it will. There will be no images.

Answer (score 0):

you will find an option to turn off auto downloading and saving of images in your mail settings.